# Проблемы при установке mysql-libmysqlclient

Tags: mysql, linux, node.js, centos

При установке mysql-libmysqlclient выдает ошибки.

```
$ npm install mysql-libmysqlclient
npm WARN package.json moniker@0.1.2 No repository field.
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mysql-libmysqlclient
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mysql-libmysqlclient
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nan
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nan

> mysql-libmysqlclient@1.6.0 install /home/web/game/node_modules/mysql-libmysqlclient
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/home/web/game/node_modules/mysql-libmysqlclient/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/mysql_bindings/src/mysql_bindings.o
In file included from ../src/mysql_bindings.cc:17:
../src/./mysql_bindings_connection.h:11:19: warning: mysql.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ../src/mysql_bindings.cc:17:
../src/./mysql_bindings_connection.h:76: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘MYSQL’ with no type
../src/./mysql_bindings_connection.h:76: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
../src/./mysql_bindings_connection.h:82: error: ‘my_bool’ does not name a type
../src/./mysql_bindings_connection.h:189: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘MYSQL_RES’ with no type
../src/./mysql_bindings_connection.h:189: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
../src/./mysql_bindings_connection.h:191: error: ‘my_ulonglong’ does not name a type
../src/./mysql_bindings_connection.h:192: error: ‘my_ulonglong’ does not name a type
../src/./mysql_bindings_connection.h:210: error: ‘MYSQL’ has not been declared
../src/./mysql_bindings_connection.h:212: error: ‘MYSQL’ has not been declared
In file included from ../src/mysql_bindings.cc:18:
../src/./mysql_bindings_result.h:41: error: ‘MYSQL’ has not been declared
../src/./mysql_bindings_result.h:41: error: ‘MYSQL_RES’ has not been declared
../src/./mysql_bindings_result.h:43: error: ‘MYSQL_FIELD’ has not been declared
../src/./mysql_bindings_result.h:45: error: ‘MYSQL_FIELD’ has not been declared
../src/./mysql_bindings_result.h:56: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘MYSQL’ with no type
../src/./mysql_bindings_result.h:56: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
../src/./mysql_bindings_result.h:57: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘MYSQL_RES’ with no type
../src/./mysql_bindings_result.h:57: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
../src/./mysql_bindings_result.h:63: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
../src/./mysql_bindings_result.h:89: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘MYSQL_FIELD’ with no type
../src/./mysql_bindings_result.h:89: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from ../src/mysql_bindings.cc:19:
../src/./mysql_bindings_statement.h:50: error: ‘MYSQL_STMT’ has not been declared
../src/./mysql_bindings_statement.h:53: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘MYSQL_STMT’ with no type
../src/./mysql_bindings_statement.h:53: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
../src/./mysql_bindings_statement.h:55: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘MYSQL_BIND’ with no type
../src/./mysql_bindings_statement.h:55: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
../src/./mysql_bindings_statement.h:56: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘MYSQL_BIND’ with no type
../src/./mysql_bindings_statement.h:56: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
../src/./mysql_bindings_statement.h:70: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
../src/./mysql_bindings_statement.h:124: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘MYSQL_RES’ with no type
../src/./mysql_bindings_statement.h:124: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
../src/./mysql_bindings_statement.h:143: error: ‘MYSQL_BIND’ has not been declared
../src/./mysql_bindings_statement.h:145: error: ‘MYSQL_FIELD’ has not been declared
../src/mysql_bindings.cc: In function ‘void InitMysqlLibmysqlclient(v8::Handle<v8::Object>)’:
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:40: error: ‘CLIENT_COMPRESS’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:41: error: ‘CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:42: error: ‘CLIENT_IGNORE_SIGPIPE’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:43: error: ‘CLIENT_IGNORE_SPACE’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:44: error: ‘CLIENT_INTERACTIVE’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:47: error: ‘CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:48: error: ‘CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:49: error: ‘CLIENT_NO_SCHEMA’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:57: error: ‘CLIENT_REMEMBER_OPTIONS’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:60: error: ‘MYSQL_INIT_COMMAND’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:61: error: ‘MYSQL_OPT_COMPRESS’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:62: error: ‘MYSQL_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:65: error: ‘MYSQL_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:68: error: ‘MYSQL_OPT_PROTOCOL’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:69: error: ‘MYSQL_OPT_READ_TIMEOUT’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:70: error: ‘MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:73: error: ‘MYSQL_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:80: error: ‘MYSQL_OPT_WRITE_TIMEOUT’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:81: error: ‘MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_FILE’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:82: error: ‘MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_GROUP’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:83: error: ‘MYSQL_REPORT_DATA_TRUNCATION’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:84: error: ‘MYSQL_SECURE_AUTH’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:85: error: ‘MYSQL_SET_CHARSET_DIR’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:86: error: ‘MYSQL_SET_CHARSET_NAME’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:91: error: ‘STMT_ATTR_UPDATE_MAX_LENGTH’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:92: error: ‘STMT_ATTR_CURSOR_TYPE’ was not declared in this scope
../src/mysql_bindings.cc:93: error: ‘STMT_ATTR_PREFETCH_ROWS’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [Release/obj.target/mysql_bindings/src/mysql_bindings.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/home/web/game/node_modules/mysql-libmysqlclient/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/web/game/node_modules/mysql-libmysqlclient
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.24
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! mysql-libmysqlclient@1.6.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mysql-libmysqlclient@1.6.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the mysql-libmysqlclient package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls mysql-libmysqlclient
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "mysql-libmysqlclient"
npm ERR! cwd /home/web/game
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/web/game/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Может быть кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: `warning: mysql.h: No such file or directory` - очевидно не установлен пакет libmysqlclient-dev (если это debian based дистр)

Comment: Установил данные пакеты, но он все равно не находит mysql.h и далее сыпятся ошибки. Т.е все ошибки их файла mysql_bindings_connection.h.

Comment: @Jeix, `find /usr/include -name mysql.h` найдет файл?

Comment: @Fike, нет

Comment: @Jeix, вы точно установили `libmysqlclient-dev` (именно с суффиксом `-dev`? Я на ноутбуке только что поставил, и `mysql.h` после этого появился в `/usr/include/mysql`.

Comment: @Fike, Точно. Выполнял команды: sudo yum install libmysqlclient-dev libmysqlclient и sudo yum install libevent-dev libevent.

Comment: @Jeix понятно, я попутал CentOS с убунтой

С [описалова](https://github.com/Sannis/node-mysql-libmysqlclient#dependencies) на гитхабе (куда можно было и заглянуть):

> For CentOS:
> 
> \#> yum install mysql-devel

Comment: @Fike, точно, спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

> warning: mysql.h: No such file or directory

не установлены заголовочные файлы *mysql*.

в дистрибутиве *centos* это можно сделать, например, командой:

```
$ sudo yum install mysql-devel
```